# clang / gcc on MacOS: Error Expected Filename

Tags: c, macos, gcc, clang

I've just got clang running on my Mac 10.14.6, trying to run a simple HelloWorld program but I'm struggling to import/include the function library... See code below. Any help much appreciated - mega n00b alert. Isn't Mr. Robot great though.

Here's my code:

```
#import <stdio.h>

int main(void)    
{
printf("Hello, world!\n");
return 0;
}
```

and here's my error:

```
Michaels-MBP:tests mh$ gcc hello.c
hello.c:1:8: error: expected "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
#import
       ^
 hello.c:4:2: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'printf' with type
      'int (const char *, ...)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        printf("Hello, WOrld!\n");
        ^
hello.c:4:2: note: include the header <stdio.h> or explicitly provide a
      declaration for 'printf'
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Comment: There is no `#import` in C, unless it's a compiler extension.  Do you mean to use `#include <stdio.h>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `import` is unknown to C/C++, there's nothing `import` in it, it's notorious in Java & Python.

Use `#include <stdio.h>` instead.

Comment: thanks all, I think I was also making the mistake of using the '.c' extension when trying to compile the program...

Comment: @nextural No, there's no error in the command-line. That'll just generate a binary and you need to execute that.